# Jasmine unit tests not using the mock service I'm providing it

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for my functional auth guard by following [this tutorial](https://www.danywalls.com/testing-functional-guards-in-angular-15-a-step-by-step-guide), however when I am passing in the mock auth service to be able to mock isLoggedIn(), I can see that the unmocked service is still being used by Jasmine. This causes it to error out on a dependency found in AuthService

auth.guard.ts:

```
export const authGuard = (data: any) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  if (authService.isLoggedIn()) { // test errors out here due to it still calling the unmocked isLoggedIn() function
    return true;
  }

  if(data.parameters......){ // does some stuff with the data param
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

auth.guard.spec.ts:

```
  let data = {
    url: [
      {
        path: 'testpath',
        parameters: {
          src: 'testsrcparam',
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const setup = (authServiceMock: unknown) => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        authGuard,
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceMock }, // it should be using the mock service here
      ],
    });

    return TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => authGuard(data));
  };

  it('should return true if user is authenticated', () => {
    const mockAuthService: unknown = {
      isLoggedIn: () => of(true),
    };

    const guard = setup(mockAuthService); // passing mock service to setup config

    expect(guard).toBe(true);
  });
```

From what I can tell everything is set up properly to utilize the mock service, but if I put a console.log in AuthService.isLoggedIn() I can see that the unit tests are still referencing the unmocked function. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: could the reason be in ` isLoggedIn: () => true` is the correct implementation on mock, and not ` isLoggedIn: () => of(true),`?

Comment: @Andrei I actually had that at first, but it also didn't work

Comment: Any chance you have more than 1 AuthService?

Comment: +1 to double check to that the same `AuthService` is provided as the one injected in the guard. Another sanity check would be to double check / verify that actually this test is running, with `fdescribe` or `fit`. 'I can see that the unit tests are still referencing the unmocked function' what is the unmocked function? In this test nothing else is provided, so if the mock is not correct for some reason, nothing should be there instead of it.

Comment: I know the question is about this auth guard specifically, but i would suggest to check for other components/services (a login component for instance?) that might be injecting AuthService, if its not mocked correctly in all your spec files you will still see that dependency issue from AuthService in the testing output. the testing output can be a little misleading in these kinds of instances.

Comment: I tried recreating your project it works fine for me. I feel like you left out some crucial parts of your code. (I had to remove the data parameter thought to not get  `Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for authGuard: (?).`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do hope this helps as I do use to test my authguard like this.
Auth,guard.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, inject, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
 
describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let authService: AuthService
  let guard: AuthGuard;
  let routeMock: any = { snapshot: {}};
  let routeStateMock: any = { snapshot: {}, url: '/cookies'};
  let routerMock = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')}
 
  beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [AuthGuard, { provide: Router, useValue: routerMock },],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
  });
  injector = getTestBed();
  authService = injector.get(AuthService);
  guard = injector.get(AuthGuard);
});
 
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  });
 
  it('should redirect an unauthenticated user to the login route', () => {
    expect(guard.canActivate(routeMock, routeStateMock)).toEqual(false);
    expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/login']);
  });
 
  it('should allow the authenticated user to access app', () => {
    spyOn(authService, 'isLoggedIn').and.returnValue(true);
    expect(guard.canActivate(routeMock, routeStateMock)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

[And Verify the test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeXWR.png)